# Tail command- using fseek() and getline() - Output out of order

Tags: c, linux

I need help understanding how to implement the linux `tail` command in c using a combination of `fseek()` and `getline`.

I'm using `fseek()` to reach the end of file, then using a while loop to iterate backwards.

If a newline character('\n') is detected. I would printout the line, then return to the position I had reached before calling `getline` minus the position in which the '\n' was detected.

Otherwise if no '\n' is detected, then using an offset of -2 from my current position i would iterated backwards.

I understand that there are easier ways of performing the tail command that involve the buffer, but is my algorithm correct? And if so, what is the best way of implementing it.

Thanks in advance.

```
void tail(FILE *ifp, int k) {
    int line_count=0;
    char *line=NULL;
    size_t len=0;

    //go to end of file
    if(fseek(ifp,-1,SEEK_END)) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failure in reaching end of file\n");
    }

    //while loop which will iterate backward starting at the end of file until line_count = k.
    while(line_count != k) {
        //if detected a newline character, increment line_count, print out line then return back to previous position.          
        if(fgetc(ifp)=='\n') {
            getline(&line, &len, ifp);
            printf("%s", line);
            fseek(ifp,-strlen(line), SEEK_CUR);
            line_count++;
            //free(line);
        } else {
            //move back a single positon 
            fseek(ifp,-(strlen(line)+2), SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }
    //free(line);
    fclose(ifp);
    printf("-----\nfunction exited\n-------\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

- Keep the last N lines in a buffer and go forward, OR
- Start from end of the file and go backward N lines.

The second approach is more efficient considering arbitrary file sizes. So your approach is fine and the more efficient one. **However, your code needs work.**

In your code, you may want to check for the case where there are less than `k` lines in the file. Take a look at the tail implementation in GNU [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c) for more.

1) Memory leak: The memory allocated with getline needs to be freed at the end:

```
if(line)
  free(line)
```

2) When you hit a `'\n'` (your `if` becomes `true`) you should still go backward first (think about what happens with the last `'\n'` in the file, that's the first `'\n'` that you hope to hit). However, your code performs a `getline` which is going forward.

3) Your `else` does not seek a single position, it depends on the value of previous `strlen(line)` and not the current line, and you might miss some `'\n'` by this seek OR your seek might be illegal --> make sure that you don't hit the pass the start of the file while going backward.

Comment: Thank you, i had trouble with the '\n' and am just after realizing it. I will definitely be using your answer as future reference when reading a file in reverse, thank you again.